# UriFormatException : Invalid URI: Invalid port specified

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, uri

The assembly qualified string used as a parameter below for a Uri works in XAML, but gives me the error shown when used in code.

I tried every kind of UriKind with the same result. How can I fix this?

```cs
[Test]
public void LargeImageSource_IsKnown()
{
var uri = new Uri(
        "pack://application:,,,/" + 
        "MyAssembly.Core.Presentation.Wpf;component/" + 
        "Images/Delete.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

Assert.That(
        _pickerActivityCollectionVm.DeleteActivityCommand.LargeImageSource,
        Is.EqualTo(uri));
}

System.UriFormatException : Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.
at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString, UriKind uriKind)
```

## UPDATE

Based on Thomas' superb answer and my own comments about readability, I wound up using the following in my BaseTestFixture class. Hope this helps someone else.

```cs
    protected virtual void OnFixtureSetUp() {
        // logging, other one time setup stuff...

        const string scheme = "pack";
        if (!UriParser.IsKnownScheme(scheme)) {
            Assert.That(PackUriHelper.UriSchemePack, Is.EqualTo(scheme));
        }
    }
```

Comment: As a FYI note: I'm facing the same issue using a WPF window hosted into a native process.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

That's because you're executing this code while the `pack://` scheme is not yet registered. This scheme is registered when you create the `Application` object. You can add this code in the setup of your test fixture:

```cs
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    if (!UriParser.IsKnownScheme("pack"))
        new System.Windows.Application();
}
```

---

EDIT: actually it seems the `pack://` scheme is registered in the type initializer of the `PackUriHelper` class (which happens to be used by the `Application` class). So actually you don't need to create an instance of `Application`, you only need to access a static member of  `PackUriHelper` to ensure the type initializer has run:

```cs
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    string s = System.IO.Packaging.PackUriHelper.UriSchemePack;
}
```

Comment: Even better, although I did like the readability of the first version. I changed the string from 's' to 'ensurePackSchemeIsKnown' so I have a chance at remembering why I did this a week or so from now. Cheers

Comment: +1 The first code sample worked for me, but the second one didn't.  I was able to improve on the first sample a little by doing this: var current = Application.Current; accessing the Application class is enough to trigger the Application static constructor, which sets up all the Uri stuff I require....

Comment: @CameronPeters, I'm suprised the second code snippet didn't work for you, since the URI scheme is registered in the static constructor of PackUriHelper... The static constructor has to be executed before the UriSchemePack is accessed.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, In my case I need the "application" scheme, which only appears to be initialized when the Application static constructor executes....

Answer (score 13):

It appears that accessing `PackUriHelper.UriSchemePack` only registers the `pack` scheme, **not** the `application` scheme, which I needed to use the `pack://application:,,,/` syntax in my unit tests.  I therefore had to use the `new Application()` approach, which worked fine for registering both schemes.

Comment: Alternately just referencing the Application class will run the static constructor which initializes what you required. Just use this: var current = Application.Current;

Answer (score 9):

**If you're seeing this error in a Windows Store / WinRT project:**

I wasn't able to use the "pack://" syntax at all when trying to load a resource in my C# app.  What worked was ms-appx:// syntax of this kind:

```
ms-appx://[project folder]/[resource path]
```

For example, I wanted to load a resource dictionary named "styles.xaml" from a folder "core".  This URI ended up working for me:

```
dictionary.Source = new System.Uri("ms-appx:///core/styles.xaml");
```

Even though the question specified WPF, the problem seemed extremely similar but ended up having a completely different solution, which took a while to find, and existing answers didn't help at all.

**Again, this solution does not apply to WPF**