# BitmapImage throwing NotImplementedException on EndInit()

Tags: c#, wpf

I am attempting to load a bitmap image from file in a WPF window but I'm getting an exception thrown on the EndInit() line below

```
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
img.BeginInit();
img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
img.UriSource = PackUriHelper.Create(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/TestImage.png", UriKind.Absolute));
img.EndInit();
img.Freeze();
```

Exception stack trace:[image: stack trace]

Any ideas? If it's relevant at all this WPF window is being hosted in a native application.

Comment: Kindly post StackTrace as Text and **not as an Image**

Comment: `PackUriHelper.Create` doesn't seem to make sense here, as you already have a Pack URI. `img.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/TestImage.png")` is sufficient in a standard WPF app. For a non-WPF app, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6005606/1136211) may be helpful.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.packurihelper(v=vs.110).aspx) - If I don't use PackUriHelper I get a different exception "The URI prefix is not recognized"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this working now - I believe this exception was being thrown because I was attempting to resolve/load the `BitmapImage` before any of the xaml resources had loaded. I forced the initialization of the `BitmapImage` into the getter for my bound Image property and it is no longer throwing.

I also noticed that I am able to correctly able to resolve pack:// URIs directly from the XAML itself.

```
private BitmapImage _listIcon;
public BitmapImage ListIcon
{
    get
    {
        if (_listIcon == null)
        {
            _listIcon = ProvideListIcon();
        }

        return _listIcon;
    }
}

protected override BitmapImage ProvideListIcon()
{
    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/[Project];Component/Images/TestImage.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    if (img.CanFreeze)
    {
        img.Freeze();
    }

    return img;
}
```